# How to delete a Ghost User - PostgresSQL

Tags: user-account

I have a PostgresSQL ghost user that *only* appears in PostgresSQL. I can't find it anywhere else.

I'm unable to login to that user, and it can't be removed. Does anyone have any idea on how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: That user was likely created if you installed PostgreSQL.  The account could be for the DB admin or the daemon.  How it got there, is a mystery.  However, if want to keep the account, but remove it from the login screen, issue the command `sudo dscl . create /Users/PostgreSQL IsHidden 1`. Logout and it should be gone.

Comment: There's no PostgreSQL in /Users. PostgresSQL user doesn't appear on login screen too. It just appears in the menubar and not even in the Users & Groups settings.